# Flutter pageview in pageview scrollable

Tags: flutter

i design widget with Pageview in Pageview and scrolling is horizontal, that i call parent and child.
so when i scroll on child Pageview to end of page it not scroll to new page of Parrent.

Thank you!

[image: scrolling on the last page of child pageview]

My code

```
  PageView.builder(
      controller: parentPageController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, indexParent) {
        return PageView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexChild) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Parent Index : $indexParent"),
                    Text("Child Index : $indexChild"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: 5,
        );
      },
      itemCount: 10,
      pageSnapping: true,
    );
```